# Is there any efficient way to call query for list of Object other than inside forloop

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

We have use case we wanted to group student id if we have same list of books borrowed by different students, so that we can pass studentIds as List and along with Book Ids as query 1 .Instead of running query twice as query 2 . and i dont want to call service method to execute the query in loop

query 1:
[studentId1,StudentId2] and [Book1,Book2]
query 2:
like studentId1 --Book1,Book2
StudentId2-- Book1,Book2

Model

```
public class School {

  private String studentId;
  private List<String> bookIds;

}

public class StudentResponse {

  private String StudentId;
  private String totalBookCount;
  private String averageBookCount
}
```

controller

```
public class SchoolControler {

  @Value("${features.enable.query.groupByStudentBook:false}")
  private boolean IsgroupStudentByBook;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/students", method = POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
  public Results < StudentResponse > getAggregatedStudentByBook(
    @ApiParam("Get Total and Average of Book count") @RequestBody List < AggregateStudentBook > aggregateStudentBookRequest) {


    if (IsgroupStudentByBook) {
      return groupingStudentId(aggregateStudentBookRequest);
    } else {
      Collection < StudentResponse > AggregateStudentBookResponse = new ArrayList < > ();

      for (AggregateStudentBook aggregateStudentBookRequest: aggregateStudentBookRequest) {

        AggregateStudentBookResponse.addAll(StudentService.getAggregateStudentBook(aggregateStudentBookRequest.getBookIds, new ArrayList < > (Arrays.asList(aggregateStudentBookRequest.getStudentId())), false));

      }
      return new Results < > (AggregateStudentBookResponse);

    }



    private Results < StudentResponse > groupingStudentId(List < AggregateStudentBookRequest > aggregateStudentBookRequest) {
      Collection < StudentResponse > aggregateStudentResponse = new ArrayList < > ();
      List < String > studentIds = new ArrayList < > ();;
      for (int i = 0; i <= aggregateStudentBookRequest.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (studentIds.contains(aggregateStudentBookRequest.get(i).getstudentId())) {
          continue;
        }
        List < String > commonstudentIds = new ArrayList < > ();
        for (int j = 1; j < aggregatedStudentRequest.size(); j++) {
          if (studentIds.contains(aggregatedStudentRequest.get(j).getstudentId())) {
            continue;
          }
          if (i == j) {
            aggregatedstudentResponse.addAll(StudentService.getAggregatedstudentBook(aggregatedStudentRequest.get(i).getBookIds(), new ArrayList < > (Arrays.asList(aggregatedStudentRequest.get(i).getstudentId())), false));
            break;

          }
          Collections.sort(aggregatedStudentRequest.get(i).getBookIds());
          Collections.sort(aggregatedStudentRequest.get(j).getBookIds());
          if (aggregatedStudentRequest.get(i).getBookIds().containsAll(aggregatedStudentRequest.get(j).getBookIds())) {
            commonstudentIds.add(aggregatedStudentRequest.get(j).getstudentId());
            commonstudentIds.add(aggregatedStudentRequest.get(i).getstudentId());
            studentIds.add(aggregatedStudentRequest.get(j).getstudentId());
            studentIds.add(aggregatedStudentRequest.get(i).getstudentId());

          }


        }
        if (!commonstudentIds.isEmpty()) {
          aggregatedstudentResponse.addAll(StudentService.getAggregatedstudentBook(aggregatedStudentRequest.get(i).getBookIds(), commonstudentIds, false));
        }

        if (studentIds.size() == aggregatedStudentRequest.size()) {
          Results < AggregatedstudentResponse > result = new Results < > (aggregatedstudentResponse);
          return result;
        }

      }



      return new Results < > (aggregatedstudentResponse);
    }


  }
}
```

Service

```
public class StudentService {

  @Autowire
  StudentRepository studentRepository;

  public Collection < AggregateStudentBook > getAggregateStudentBook(List < String > bookIds, List < String > studentIds) {
    Collection < AggregateStudentBook > aggregateStudentBook = studentRepository.fetchAggregatedStoreTargetInventory(bookIds, studentIds);
    return aggregateStudentBook;

  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: A better solution would be using [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html)

Comment: Yes i did use group buy after adding equals and hascode method but the problem is here is need to collect two duplicate objects to a list  using below code an getting only one object from two duplicate objects which correct for ideal case but here student ids are different so need two duplicate objects.Code below

Comment: aggregateStudentBookRequest.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())) .entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1L) .map(e -> e.getKey()) .collect(Collectors.toList()) .forEach(aggregateStudentBookRequest -> System.out.println(aggregateStudentBookRequest.getStudentId()+"==>"+aggregateStudentBookRequest. getBookIds()));